# How to make requests to a tcp socket and handle response in SWI Prolog?

Tags: sockets, prolog, swi-prolog

I want to handle establish a connection to the MongoDB server and it works allready. Now I want to send and recieve requests via the socket I've established, but I don't know how.

Here is my code so far:

```
:- module(_, [
    new_connection/3,
    new_socket/3,
    host/1,
    port/1 ]).

host(localhost). port(27017).

new_connection(Host, Port, Connection) :-
    new_socket(Host, Port, Socket),
    Connection = connection(Socket).

new_socket(Host, Port, Socket) :-
        socket:tcp_socket(SocketId),
        socket:tcp_connect(SocketId, Host:Port),
        socket:tcp_open_socket(SocketId, StreamPair).
```

Response:

```
new_connection(localhost, 27017, Connection).
Connection = connection(socket(<stream>(0000013B7C59CEF0), <stream>(0000013B7C59D000))).
```

The socket is opened and I got a response, but how can I make requests and handle the next response of the socket?

(Edit: I know there allready exists prolongo, but since days I'm just trying to make this run, but since this is 10years old, some parts of the code seems deprecated, so I try this from scratch.)

Comment: I would probably write a thread which blocks waiting for a data unit (e.g. a JSON block), and, once received, appends it to an open list, waking up a frozen goal - and for writing have a frozen goal that is waits for a new element to be appended to a list so that a data unit can be written to the socket output. There must be a library for that.

Comment: Isn't ist possible to send messages in between the input and the output stream? So just by using the allready established socket?

Comment: Yes, but the streams are "raw" - i.e. there is some data format on top using serialized data structures (maybe JSON, maybe binary PDUs) and a protocol using those structures that says when to send them, when to wait for them, for errors to look for, how to respond to problems etc. Unless it is telnet-like "text exchange", i.e. you send a query as a string and you get an answer as pure text?